# Is there a way to evaluate more than one string inside of a string.contains() method?

Tags: c#, string, lambda, case-insensitive, string-comparison

```
if (description.ToUpper().Contains("BOUGHT") || description.ToUpper().Contains("PURCHASE"))
```

The code above is what I have and I wondered if I had a longer list of strings for the same condition, how I would do it without making the code too long.  Maybe a lambda expression?

Comment: You could and should cache the results of `description.ToUpper`.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `ToUpper` at all... use `IndexOf` with an appropriate `StringComparison`. Upper-casing is culture-sensitive in sometimes-surprising ways.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the answers.  I've adopted concepts from almost all. :D

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no built in function. But it's not hard to write it yourself:

```
string[] needles = new string[]{"BOUGHT", "PURCHASE"};
string haystack = description.ToUpperInvariant();
bool found = needles.Any(needle=> haystack.Contains(needle));
```

I only convert `hackstack` to upper once to improve performance.

Alternatively you could use `IndexOf(needle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)>=0`:

```
string[] needles = new string[]{"BOUGHT", "PURCHASE"};
string haystack = description;
bool found = needles.Any(needle=> haystack.IndexOf(needle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)>=0);
```

---

You should not use `ToUpper()` here, since that uses the current culture. Using the current culture can lead to unexpected problems on some computers, for example `i` does not uppercase to `I` when using the Turkish culture.

There might still some subtle problems remaining where `ToUpperInvariant()` on both sides and a case insensitive comparison might return different results, but that's only relevant if you have unusual characters in both your haystack and needles.

Comment: Why not just `needles.Contains(haystack)` ? Edit: I see the problem, my bad. Leaving here to show what NOT to do :)

Comment: @leppie because that requires a match of the whole string.

Comment: @leppie: `haystack` might be your life story, `needles` is just single words.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Noticed and decided `Regex` is the right thing (TM) here :)

Answer (score 2):

You can rework the code to something like this:

```
var words = new[] { "BOUGHT", "PURCHASE" };
var desc = description.ToUpper();
if(words.Any(w => description.Contains(w)) {
    // something matched
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (someCollectionOfStrings.Any(string => originalString.Contains(string))
{
    //stuff
}
```

Comment: This lost the case insensitivity.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - yes, but he didn't ask for case insensitivity. He asked for a means to check multiple strings for a condition, preferably in a lambda expression. That is what I posted.

Comment: The original code uses `ToUpper` and uppercase keywords. So I'm pretty sure he wants case insensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, string.Join("|", strings));
```

You might have to escape the strings if they contain Regex control characters.

Answer (score 1):

[Use a regular expression:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktzf2d23.aspx)

```
  if (Regex.IsMatch(description, "purchase|bought", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) {
     // ...
  }
```

Comment: +1. This should be compilable into a state-machine that should give better performance than calling Contains multiple times (whether through || or Any).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool ContainsOneOfManyIgnoreCase(this string str, params string [] items)
    {
      return items.Any(x => str.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1);
    }
```